# Bash - if any process is killed, exit without passing to the next steps

Tags: bash

I have such a bash file;

```
./process1
./process2
./process3
./process4
./process5
```

Let's say I run this bash script, and `process2` is killed for some reason. Without passing to `process3`, I directly want to exit. How can I manage this?

Thanks,

Comment: You should also consider whether `make` might be a more appropriate tool for the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it so:

```
./process1 && ./process2 && ./process3 && ./process4 && ./process5
```

Answer (score 3):

Just exit if *non-zero* exit code:

```
./process1 || exit
```

and so on ...

Another way in `bash`, use `-e` flag:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
```

> -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a **non-zero** status.

Comment: Downvote: Explicitly examining `$?` is a beginner antipattern.  The shell's flow control constructs all examine this variable behind the scene; you should almost never need to look at it directly.  The proper way to do what you describe is simply `./process1 || exit` (which has the added benefit that the exit code from `process1` is propagated back to the caller).

Comment: Good point @tripleee . Thanks

Comment: That was quick. Downvote redacted.